# Wait for an unknown number of tasks, then block any new ones

Tags: .net, multithreading

What is the best synchronization primitive/pattern in .NET to wait until an unknown number of threads/tasks have finished, then immediately block any new ones from executing?

Basically something like a collection of tasks with `Add` and `WaitForAllThenDispose`. `WaitForAllThenDispose` allows new tasks to be added during the wait and correctly waits for all of them.

But as soon as all active tasks are completed and there are no concurrent calls to `Add`, it moves to dispose and blocks any new tasks from being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern I ended with at the moment:

```
public class ActionScheduler {
    private readonly CountdownEvent _allCompleted = new CountdownEvent(1);
    private volatile bool _disposed;

    public void Schedule(Action action) {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("ActionScheduler");

        // this feels ugly:
        try {
            _allCompleted.AddCount();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) {
            // should only happen after the dispose/wait has completed
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("ActionScheduler");
        }

        ScheduleInternal(() => {
            try {
                action();
            }
            finally {
                _allCompleted.Signal();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ScheduleInternal(Action action) {
        // some async scheduling irrelevant to the example
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        _allCompleted.Signal(); // removing initial +1
        _allCompleted.Wait();
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only change I can think of is make `_disposed` volatile to prevented cross thread cached reads.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good point, yesterday I have considered that but decided against it as it did not add to safety. But today I think it is a good idea.